# How to use variable inside variable in cell .address

Tags: excel, vba

I have several column of discontinuous data, each column contain some continues reading which needs to be summed up. So summation at different ranges is required. Summation will only be made if x is greater than 1 and its value define the size of range (number of row to be selected above the active cell) .  However "rng1 = .. address" resulted an application-defined or object-defined error. My code is not so neat but I'm sure all variable hold desired value, please help..

```
Sub Dynamic_rowsRangeNumbers()
Dim rng1 As String, rng2 As String
Dim nrow As Integer
Dim x, ncol As Integer

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5").Activate
For ncol = 2 To 4
  For nrow = 3 To 28
  x = Cells(nrow, 216 + ncol).Value 
  rng1 = Cells(nrow - x + 1, ncol).Address *** run-time error 1004
  rng2 = ActiveCell.Address

  'If reference cell has value FZ>=1 Then
   If (Cells(nrow, 216 + ncol).Value >= 1) Then
   Cells(nrow, 254 + ncol).Formula = "=sum(" & (rng1) & ":" & (rng2) & ")"
   End If
  Next nrow
Next ncol
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the value of x when it fails?

Comment: Probably not linked to your problem but `Dim rng1, rng2 As String` will only declare `rng2` as `string` while `rng1` will be seen as a `variant` type variable.  You should write `Dim rng1 As String, rng2 As String`

Comment: My gut feeling is that moving your `If (Cells(nrow, 216 + ncol).Value >= 1) Then` statement so that it is directly after the `For nrow = 3 To 28` statement may fix things.  Even if it doesn't fix things, it should probably be moved - none of the three lines in-between those two statements is needed except **within** the `If` block.  (But I guess you could leave the `x = ...` line where it is, and then have `If x >= 1 Then` after it.)

Comment: @SJR, I remove rng1 and print x just to check the value, it match the value in column.  but return to original code, it give ncol = 3, nrow = 3 (stop at row 3?) and x = " ".

Comment: @simpLEMAn,ya  thank you..

Comment: @YowE3K, in that case the error shift to "x = Cells(nrow, 216 + ncol).Value"

Comment: If `Cells(nrow, 216 + ncol).Value` is not numeric, you can't treat it as a numeric value - i.e. you can't do `3 - " " + 1` and you can't test that `" " >= 1`.  Check whether the value is `IsNumeric` before you do anything.  (I.e. wrap everything inside your inner `For` within an `If IsNumeric(Cells(nrow, 216 + ncol).Value) Then` block.)

Comment: What is the `ActiveCell` in your code?  Is it a cell that user selects before they run the macro?  (I'll post some code as an answer, but I might need to edit it based on your reply to this comment.)

Comment: @YowE3K, No, ActiveCell is my looping row and column.

Comment: If you intended `ActiveCell` to be `Cells(nrow, ncol)`, you would need to **make** that the active cell.  (I could guess that that was your intention, which is why I changed your code in my answer, but VBA has no way of guessing that - one reason why humans aren't obsolete yet!!)

Answer (score 0):

You can't use non-numeric values in numeric calculations, so test that the value is numeric before doing anything:

```
Sub Dynamic_rowsRangeNumbers()
    Dim rng1 As String, rng2 As String
    Dim nrow As Long
    Dim x As Long, ncol As Long

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet5")
        For ncol = 2 To 4
            For nrow = 3 To 28
                If IsNumeric(.Cells(nrow, 216 + ncol).Value) Then
                    x = .Cells(nrow, 216 + ncol).Value 
                    'If reference cell has value FZ>=1 Then
                    If x >= 1 Then
                        rng1 = .Cells(nrow - x + 1, ncol).Address
                        'This next line seems wrong - you were never moving ActiveCell
                        'rng2 = ActiveCell.Address
                        'I think you wanted
                        rng2 = .Cells(nrow, ncol).Address

                        .Cells(nrow, 254 + ncol).Formula = "=sum(" & rng1 & ":" & rng2 & ")"
                    End If
                End If
            Next nrow
        Next ncol
    End With
End Sub
```